# Using Pandas to shift only a slice of a DatetimeIndex series and put it back in to the file shifted ahead

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, slice, shift

I have a time series that had a DST issue. Simply put, I am wanting to pull out a slice of the series and shift it ahead an hour (minutely data), and then put the shifted slice back in and ffill any missing values with 0.

Here is the data I need to shift an hour:

```
2014,345,0744,0,0
2014,345,0745,0,0
2014,345,0746,0,0
2014,345,0747,0,.018
2014,345,0748,.052,.215
2014,345,0749,.155,.268
2014,345,0750,.172,.375
2014,345,0751,.396,.429
2014,345,0752,.413,.447
```

Here is an example of where I need the above to be (shifted ahead an hour):

```
2014,344,0844,0,0
2014,344,0845,0,0
2014,344,0846,0,0
2014,344,0847,0,.054
2014,344,0848,0,.107
2014,344,0849,.138,.197
2014,344,0850,.189,.125
2014,344,0851,.276,.179
2014,344,0852,.155,.143
2014,344,0853,.103,.161
```

My approach has been to slice out the time chunk that I need to shift data by an hour, shift the data by an hour, and then **replace the original data with the shifted slice.**

So far I have tried this:

```
slice = df['20141211 02:00':'20141227 22:00'] #The slice needing to be shifted

shifted = slice.shift(periods=1, freq='60T') #Move the datetime values forward an hour

df.merge(shifted, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

The slice and shifting worked fine, but the last line of code is not doing what I would like it to. I have also tried it with all variants of left_index and left_on...the closest I get is what the above gives me:

```
    3_x 4_x 3_y 4_y
datetime                
2014-12-11 07:30:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:31:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:32:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:33:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:34:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:35:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:36:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:37:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:38:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:39:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:40:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:41:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:42:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:43:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:44:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:45:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:46:00 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:47:00 0.000   0.018   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:48:00 0.052   0.215   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:49:00 0.155   0.268   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:50:00 0.172   0.375   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:51:00 0.396   0.429   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 07:52:00 0.413   0.447   0.000   0.000
```

Notice how the sift has worked, and it has added another couple columns, but I wanted to replace the original columns (df, on the left) with shifted (those 2 on the right). To start values around 8:47 not 7:47, i.e.:

```
2014-12-11 08:44:00 6.338   7.080   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 08:45:00 7.170   8.030   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 08:46:00 7.720   8.150   0.000   0.000
2014-12-11 08:47:00 6.959   7.780   0.000   0.018
2014-12-11 08:48:00 6.166   6.991   0.052   0.215
2014-12-11 08:49:00 5.029   6.061   0.155   0.268
2014-12-11 08:50:00 4.444   5.632   0.172   0.375
```

Comment: If you identify where the duplicates exist you could use `resample('col_with_dups', how='mean')`. See here --> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Comment: The duplicate indexes (shifted) are those I am trying to set back into the original data frame (df). I am wondering if I am wanting to use another method than the one I used above; perhaps merge or join? Effectively I want to replace the df indexes with shifted ones, so is there a "replace" method?

Comment: Well you could `merge` the two data frames and then specify if you want to keep the indices from either the right hand side data frame or left hand side. `df.merge(shifted, left_index=False, right_index=True)` might work for you instead of your last line.

Comment: I am having a hard time incorporating the desired changes using merge, but have gotten the data merged in, just not correctly (i.e.: replacing the original slice). Please see the edited question above for examples.

Comment: Try `df.update(shifted)` rather than your merge.

Comment: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis                                     Does the data where shifted will go need to be deleted for that method to work?

Comment: Perhaps `df.update(shifted).reset_index()` or `df.update(shifted.reset_index())` might work then.

Comment: `df.combine_first(shifted)` or `shifted.combine_first(df)`.

Answer (score 0):

After many trials and errors I have found a way to remove a slice from a Dataframe indexed by datetime, shift it an hour, and then combine it back into the original dataframe. Thanks to aux_lacy for the help. See below:

```
In [153]:

slice = df['20141211 02:00':'20141227 22:00'] # The chunk to slice out and shift
In [154]:

shifted = slice.shift(periods=1, freq='60T') # The shift ahead an hour (minutely data)
In [162]:

df = shifted.combine_first(df) # combine the 2 data frames (luckily the values needed to be zeros anyway, so not sure if that would have bee something else to consider, but in this case it worked!)
```